# Jquery-ui: align multiple icons and text

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm having a hell of a time aligning two jquery-ui icons and text in the middle of the line in a header. (code blow). Can anyone assist pretty pleeeeease?

```
<div class="ui-widget-header">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-wrench"></span>Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not perfectly clear on what you are wanting as an output.

If you are trying to get the icons and the text to all appear on one line, you do that by creating a new CSS class:

```
.ui-icon.inline { display:inline-block; }​
.ui-widget-header.center { text-align:center; }
```

And then adding that class to your icons:

```
<div class="ui-widget-header">
    <span class="ui-icon inline ui-icon-close"></span>
    <span class="ui-icon inline ui-icon-wrench"></span>
    Text
</div>​
```

If you want them to then be horizontally centered in the div you could then change the `div` to:

```
<div class="ui-widget-header center">
```